# Working with text box onchange and ajax load for dropdown jQuery PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have to do something like this and here is my code

1. When start and end date is completed, I need to enable the author select box.
2. The author names should be dynamically loaded from database based on the start and end date.

My form is ready, and the script is done with my minimal knowledge. Needs some expert help in completing my code.

Any help in doing this will be highly appreciable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#to_date_change").change('input',function() {
        $('#author_code').prop('disabled', false);
    });
</script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Start Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">End Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Resources</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="start_date_change" id="start_date_change" name="from_date_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="end_date_change" id="end_date_change" name="to_date_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text">
            </td>
            <td class="text-justify" nowrap="nowrap">
                <select disabled="disabled" name="author_code_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="author_code" class="author_code" style="width: 250px;">
                    <option value="">Select Author</option>
                    <?php 
                    // ............. this should come from ajax load based on start and end date ................
                    echo "<option value=".$tbemp[$r][0].">".$tbemp[$r][0]." - ".$tbemp[$r][2]."</option>";
                    // ............. this should come from ajax load based on start and end date ................
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the answer is already on your tag :) use AJAX, using the user input, request values from server, select some data, return a response, use the response from the server and loop each row

Comment: "Hello, My name is code indentation". "My pleasure". Anyway, use AJAX, as you suggested it by yourself in the tags :). Have you ever used it?

Answer (score 2):

Use ajax call to send data and fetch result, use that result to display.

```
var start_date,end_date;
//fetch and assign the date to these variables

$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/script/for/processing",
    type: "post",
    data: {start: start_date,end: end_date}
}).done(function(data){
    //data contains the result returned from the script. 
    // use that data to display.
});
```

Comment: @user3350885 would you consider this answer as correct and mark it